# Code to color dupes in row 1 colors only one cell of dupe

Tags: excel, vba

I want to check for dupes in `Row One`

The Code below works fine for column ranges like:

```
 myrng = Range("C2:C" & Range("C65536").End(xlUp).Row)

 and

 If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("C2:C" & cel.Row), cel) = 1 Then
```

But if I change to Row 1 the code only highlights one cell of the duplicates

Thanks

First Row

```
Sub HilightDupsRow1()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim cel As Variant
Dim myrng As Range
Dim clr As Long, LC As Long, cnt1 As Long, cnt2 As Long


    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Nodes")
    With ws
         LC = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
         Set myrng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, LC))

      myrng.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
      clr = 3
      For Each cel In myrng
          If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(myrng, cel) > 1 Then
              If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, cel.Column)) cel) > 1 Then
                  cel.Interior.ColorIndex = clr
                  clr = clr + 1
              Else
                  cel.Interior.ColorIndex = myrng.Cells(WorksheetFunction.Match(cel.Value, myrng, False), 1).Interior.ColorIndex
              End If
          End If
      Next cel
   End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You should say clearly. Your question is not clear.

Comment: Your missing a comma here,`.Cells(1, cel.Column)) cel`.   So you want each duplicate to be it's own separate color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Collections to get the unique values, then loop through the collections to highlight the duplicates.

```
Sub UsingCollection()
    Dim cUnique As Collection
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim vNum As Variant
    Dim LstCol As Long
    Dim c As Long, clr As Long, x, r As Range

    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Nodes")
    With sh

        LstCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, LstCol))
        Set cUnique = New Collection
        Rng.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        clr = 3

        On Error Resume Next
        For Each Cell In Rng.Cells
            cUnique.Add Cell.Value, CStr(Cell.Value)
        Next Cell
        On Error GoTo 0

        For Each vNum In cUnique
            For c = 1 To LstCol
                Set r = .Cells(1, c)
                x = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, c)), r)
                If r = vNum Then
                    If x > 1 Then
                        r.Interior.ColorIndex = clr
                    End If
                End If
            Next c
            clr = clr + 1
        Next vNum

    End With

End Sub
```

[image]