# Give unique reference to each unique value

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel table that has some duplicates and we currently have a count of these however I want to populate a unique number for each duplicate. e.g.

```
Number  Count   Sequence
1          2    1
1          2    1
2          3    2
2          3    2
2          3    2
3          4    3
3          4    3
3          4    3
3          4    3
4          2    4
4          2    4
5          5    5
5          5    5
5          5    5
5          5    5
5          5    5
```

I was playing with the following IF statement but I want it to check through the whole range and check if it has any in a wrong order but still the same.

```
=IF(IF(IF(A2=A1,TRUE,FALSE)=FALSE,1,0)>=0,IF(IF(A2=A1,TRUE,FALSE)=FALSE,1,0)+D1,IF(IF(A2=A1,TRUE,FALSE)=FALSE,1,0))
```

is this possible?

Comment: Why dont you just add a column with a unique number?

Comment: There are thousands of records and I wanted it to not give a unique number if it has a match further down the sheet.

Comment: So you only want an ID if the rows underneeth each other are duplicates?

Comment: They might not be directly underneath each other but yes.

Comment: So then, I still do not understand why you dont add another colum called ID counting from 1 to NNN. Which would be your unique ID. You could add an interval of 10 to add rows later on...

Comment: Why don't you sort the data, then you don't have to worry about other possible duplicates further down the list and can just give each "block" a unique ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will add the unique ref into the a Column which is 3 columns up from what every you set col equal to.

It also requires that col + 3 to be blank, this will make the checking easier.

```
Sub SomeSub()

    Dim Array1 As Variant
    Dim Array2 As Variant

    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        LastRow = .Rows(.Rows.Count).Row
    End With

    'Setting up the array for assigning each row value to the array
    ReDim Array1((LastRow + 1))
    ReDim Array2((LastRow + 1))

    'Here youwill set what column is the "Number" Column
    col = 1

    'Assigning the row data into the arrays
    'Starting at 2 to skip the title row
    For r = 2 To LastRow
            'Values in Column 1 go to Array1
            Array1(r) = Cells(r, col)
            'Values in Column 2 go to Array2
            Array2(r) = Cells(r, col + 1)
    Next r

    'Setting unquie ref to 1
    Seq = 1
    'Running through each row of data
    For i = 2 To LastRow

        'col + 3 refers to a column on beyond the Sequence colum
        'If the column is blank then that row has not been checked yet
        If Cells(i, col + 3) = "" Then

            'Assign the Uniqui ref to the row
            Cells(i, col + 3).Value = Seq

            'Running through the rest of the rows to check if they are like the current row
            For n = i + 1 To (LastRow)

                'If cell is blank then the row has been checked
                If Cells(n, col + 3) = "" Then

                    'Array(i) is the current row
                    'Array(n) are the leading rows after row i
                    'If the current row is the same as any leading row then the uniquie ref = seq
                    If Array1(i) = Array1(n) And Array2(i) = Array2(n) Then Cells(n, col + 3).Value = Seq

                'Else a value has been added
                Else

                    'Do nothing

                End If

            Next n

            'Increment the seq
            Seq = Seq + 1

        'Ending the If Cells(i, col + 3) = "" Then
        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first loop through the column and get the unique items using collections.

This part of the code:

```
   On Error Resume Next
        For Each Cell In Rng.Cells
            cUnique.Add Cell.Value, CStr(Cell.Value)
        Next Cell
```

Will only get the unique items, as a collection of items cannot have duplicates.

Use this to Number the duplicates.Change the sheet name as required.

```
    Sub NumberDupes()
    Dim cUnique As Collection
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim vNum As Variant
    Dim LstRw As Long
    Dim c As Long, clr As Long, x, r As Range

    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet2")
    With sh
        .Columns("B:B").ClearContents
        LstRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(LstRw, 1))
        Set cUnique = New Collection
        Rng.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        clr = 1

        On Error Resume Next
        For Each Cell In Rng.Cells
            cUnique.Add Cell.Value, CStr(Cell.Value)
        Next Cell
        On Error GoTo 0

        For Each vNum In cUnique
            For c = 1 To LstRw
                Set r = .Cells(c, 1)
                x = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(c, 1)), r)
                If r = vNum Then
                    If x > 1 Then
                        r.Offset(, 1) = clr
                    End If
                End If
            Next c
            clr = clr + 1
        Next vNum

    End With

End Sub
```

Use this to Color the Duplicates, this will work on a small scale, depends on how many unique items there are, it's cool example though. Edited code from my answer [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33794540/code-to-color-dupes-in-row-1-colors-only-one-cell-of-dupe/33798531#33798531)

```
Sub ColorDupes()
    Dim cUnique As Collection
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim vNum As Variant
    Dim LstRw As Long
    Dim c As Long, clr As Long, x, r As Range

    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet2")
    With sh

        LstRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(LstRw, 1))
        Set cUnique = New Collection
        Rng.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        clr = 3

        On Error Resume Next
        For Each Cell In Rng.Cells
            cUnique.Add Cell.Value, CStr(Cell.Value)
        Next Cell
        On Error GoTo 0

        For Each vNum In cUnique
            For c = 1 To LstRw
                Set r = .Cells(c, 1)
                x = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(c, 1)), r)
                If r = vNum Then
                    If x > 1 Then
                        r.Interior.ColorIndex = clr
                    End If
                End If
            Next c
            clr = clr + 1
        Next vNum

    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In `C1` just `1` and in `C2`:

```
=MIN(IF(($A$2:A2=A3)*($B$2:B2=B3),$D$2:D2,MAX($D$2:D2)+1))
```

> This is an array formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

and simply autofill down from `C3`

hmm... i think i got it wrong :/

if only looking at Column A then this should be enough:

```
=MIN(IF($A$2:A2=A3,$D$2:D2,MAX($D$2:D2)+1))
```

> This is an array formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

looking at your formula it can be shortened:

```
=IF(IF(IF(A2=A1,TRUE,FALSE)=FALSE,1,0)>=0,IF(IF(A2=A1,TRUE,FALSE)=FALSE,1,0)+D1,IF(IF(A2=A1,TRUE,FALSE)=FALSE,1,0))
  'IF(A2=A1,TRUE,FALSE)=FALSE ==>> A1<>A2    
=IF(IF(A1<>A2,1,0)>=0,IF(A1<>A2,1,0)+D1,IF(A1<>A2,1,0))
  'IF(A1<>A2,1,0)>=0 ==>> TRUE
=IF(TRUE,IF(A1<>A2,1,0)+D1,IF(A1<>A2,1,0))
  'IF(TRUE => allways true
=IF(A1<>A2,1,0)+D1
  'last skip
=D1+(A1<>A2)
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work as expected. I have decided to just use my IF statement.

Comment: for the second formula -> each item in A will get its own unique number... having a dublicate will have the same id... isnt that what you wanted?

Comment: @AlanTreanor i forgot to mention that this are array-formulas... sorry