# Color code duplicate entries in a field of an excel using alternating colors

Tags: mysql, vba, excel, duplicates

I have extracted a list of duplicates from a MySQL database to an excel sheet.  This excel shows that we have duplicates (~1,900) and sometimes triplicate entries based on a single field of the excel sheet.

For example:

```
10019
10019
10048
10048
10060
10060
```

How can I go about coloring the duplicate pairs so that they can be easily visualized as a pair for every pair.  Basically I would like to color fill each duplicate pair with an alternating color so that I could easily see the pairs.

Comment: Similar question & answer here, http://stackoverflow.com/a/35252399

Comment: There is a nice [SUMPRODUCT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumproduct-function-4e0bffa7-4291-4635-a61f-6aaa9399e7ff) combined with the [ISODD function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ISODD-function-1208A56D-4F10-4F44-A5FC-648CAFD6C07A) that would make a nice Conditional formatting rule but 1900 rows is simply too much for the cyclic processing. The calculation lag is in the minutes, not seconds. I'd suggest some VBA or a helper column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process you are talking about is call 'duplicate banding'. A pair of [Scripting.Dictionary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251825.aspx) objects should take care of this easily.

```
Sub colorDuplicateColor2()
    Dim d As Long, dODDs As Object, dEVNs As Object, vTMPs As Variant
    Dim bOE As Boolean
    
    Set dODDs = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set dEVNs = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dODDs.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    dEVNs.CompareMode = vbTextCompare
    
    With Worksheets("Sheet7")
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        
        With .Range(.Cells(1, "C"), .Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))
            
            With .Columns(1)
                .Cells.Interior.Pattern = xlNone
            End With
            
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Offset(1, 0)
                vTMPs = .Value2
            End With
            
            For d = LBound(vTMPs, 1) To UBound(vTMPs, 1)
                'the dictionary Items have to be strings to be used as filter criteria
                If Not (dODDs.exists(vTMPs(d, 1)) Or dEVNs.exists(vTMPs(d, 1))) Then
                    If bOE Then
                        dODDs.Item(vTMPs(d, 1)) = CStr(vTMPs(d, 1))
                    Else
                        dEVNs.Item(vTMPs(d, 1)) = CStr(vTMPs(d, 1))
                    End If
                    bOE = Not bOE
                End If
            Next d
            
            With .Columns(1)
                .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=dODDs.Items, Operator:=xlFilterValues
                .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Interior.Color = RGB(210, 210, 210)
                'use this to band the entire row
                '.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(210, 210, 210)
                'use this to band the row within the UsedRange
                'Intersect(.Parent.UsedRange, .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow).Interior.Color = RGB(210, 210, 210)
                .AutoFilter
                .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=dEVNs.Items, Operator:=xlFilterValues
                .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 200, 200)
                .Cells(1).EntireRow.Interior.Pattern = xlNone
            End With
            
        End With
        
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
    
    dODDs.RemoveAll: Set dODDs = Nothing
    dEVNs.RemoveAll: Set dEVNs = Nothing
    Erase vTMPs

End Sub
```

The data must be sorted on the duplicate criteria column of course.

[image: duplicateBanding]

This process could be easily adjusted for full row or row-within-data-block banding.

Comment: Works great in color coding the pairs, how would I have this highlight the entire row and not the individual cells.

Comment: I had thought that might be something to augment the process. Do you mean the whole row (A:XFD) or the extents of the data block (maybe the limit of column header labels across row 1)?

Comment: I offered two alternatives but unfortunately, I cannot test them right this moment.

Comment: It would be ideal to color rows to the width that there are column headers.

Comment: Work's great @Jeeped except it also highlights the spreadsheets headers.

Comment: Although I missed it, that fix should have been pretty obvious. The header label for the column was uncolored already, that just needed to be extended across the first row.

Comment: Jeeped, anyway to color the non-duplicate rows with another color?

Comment: Sure. Just populate another dictionary with the non-duplicates (duplicate rejects). Seems like [another question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188625) though.