# Color Rows Based on Repeated Values - excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to simplify an excel file I receive every week for my team's travel plans.

It has the team member's name, flight #, and arrival time.

I have team members come in on different flight sometimes. I like to visually see who will arrive at what time so I can easily make rental car arrangements. If a group arrives at 1:06, I'll highlight those together and another at 6:55 - I'll highlight those. We could have as many as 15 different flight plans. I currently use conditional formatting to identify the common ones, but since I do this every week for 50 people it would be convenient to through into a vba module to run. ( I already have a module reformatting some columns/rows).

I've looked at repeating code identifiers and this as my main resource
[Compare Dates/Times](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/compare-dates-times.html) but no luck so far.

Picture of what I do now:
 [highlight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDoWr.png)

Comment: See [Color code duplicate entries in a field of an excel using alternating colors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35437981/color-code-duplicate-entries-in-a-field-of-an-excel-using-alternating-colors/35448517#35448517).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I have coded is that the data is formatted into a table, then unique values in the 'Flight #' column are calculated. The data is then sequentially filtered by these values and the rows are coloured from a predetermined palette (which can be altered).

```
Sub FormatDuplicateRows()

    Dim wsFlight As Worksheet: Set wsFlight = Worksheets("Flights")

    On Error Resume Next
    If Not wsFlight.ListObjects("Flights") Is Nothing Then wsFlight.ListObjects("Flights").Unlist
    On Error GoTo 0

    wsFlight.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("A1").CurrentRegion, , xlYes).Name = "Flights"
    Dim tblFlight As ListObject: Set tblFlight = wsFlight.ListObjects("Flights")

    Dim Fld As Long: Fld = tblFlight.ListColumns("Flight #").Range.Column

    Dim Dict As Object: Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For Each Cell In tblFlight.ListColumns("Flight #").DataBodyRange
        If Not Dict.Exists(Cell.Value) Then Dict.Add Cell.Value, Cell.Address
    Next

    Dim Colours() As String: Colours = Split("&HD9E9FD,&HF3EEDB,&HECE0E5,&HDDF1EA,&HDCDDF2,&HCCFFFF", ",")
    Dim i As Long: i = 0
    With tblFlight
        .TableStyle = "TableStyleLight1"
        .ShowTableStyleRowStripes = False
        For Each Value In Dict.Keys
            .Range.AutoFilter Field:=Fld, Criteria1:=Value
            .DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Interior.Color = Colours(i)
            i = IIf(i = UBound(Colours), 0, i + 1)
        Next Value
        .Range.AutoFilter Field:=Fld
    End With

End Sub
```

You can alter the palette to your requirements and the palette will auto-repeat once all the colours have been used once

********* UPDATE **********

To get the colour values for the array I coded the following function

```
Public Function GetColour(rngSrc As Range) As String
    GetColour = "&H" & Application.WorksheetFunction.Dec2Hex(rngSrc.Interior.Color)
End Function
```

Then in an excel workbook, I just placed the formula =GetColour("A1") in "A2" and altered the fill colour of some cells along row 1 then drag-dropped the formula to get the hex values of the fill colours I wanted

Comment: Thank you so much - This works perfectly! Literally saving me lots of time! Is there a good source for the color pallete?